# What usb-c to usb-c cable for Kinect azure

Tags: usb, azurekinect

I'm trying to connect the kinect azure to my computer with only a usb-c to usb-c cable following the https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/Kinect-dk/hardware-specification page.
I've tried few but non of them seems to work. Have some of you ever tried one and know it's working ?
If so, could you give me the references please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this topic about host controllers the Azure Kinect works with. You may a have host controller that doesn't work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/Kinect-dk/troubleshooting#usb3-host-controller-compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a 1m USB 3.1 C2G cable and a 2m Thunderbolt 3 Cable Matters cable without any issues. Neither are active cables. Both have been used successfully with PD (my laptop) and non-PD (my desktop) ports. Please consult the manual of your computer to determine if your type-c port is USB 3.1 type-c compliant.